# Size of Modal in Angular template for abp.io

Tags: abp, abp.io

I can see that there are references to using `size="Large"` when using `<abp-modal>` in ABP.io commercial, however this does not seem to apply to Angular. Is there a way to specify a size for a modal?

Using ABP.io 7.3 currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass options to `abp-modal` as follows:

```html
<abp-modal [(visible)]="visible" [busy]="modalBusy" [options]="{ size: 'sm' }">
```

Allowed size options are: 'sm' | 'lg' | 'xl' |

---

### References

- https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Modal#options
- https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModalOptions